# Cleaning CSV/Dataframe of size ~40GB using Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am kind of newbie to big data world. I have a initial CSV which has a data size of ~40GB but in some kind of shifted order. I mean if you see initial CSV, for Jenny there is no age, so sex column value is shifted to age and remaining column value keeps shifting till the last element in the row.

I want clean/process this CVS using dataframe with Spark in Scala. I tried quite a few solution with withColumn() API and all, but nothing worked for me.

If anyone can suggest me some sort of logic or API available which is out there to solve this in a cleaner way. I might not need proper solution but pointers will also do. Help much appreciated!!

**Initial CSV/Dataframe**

[image: Initial CSV/Dataframe]

**Required CSV/Dataframe**

[image]

**EDIT:**

This is how I'm reading the data:

```
val spark = SparkSession .builder .appName("SparkSQL")
  .master("local[*]") .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp") 
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.option("header", true").csv("path/to/csv.csv")
```

Comment: This happen only when there is problem with data. if you use Spark API to read CSV file it truncate column on the bases of Comma( ,). There are few extra commas in row that's why it is not working properly.

Comment: @Nasruddin try to read it as val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true").load("path/to/csv.csv") if still not working then there is problem with data. Data is not properly formatted. In that case you have to check if there is any extra comma then that need to be replace.

Comment: @Nasruddin use option("escape",",") during reading of file it will help you to resolve your problem if data is comma seprated

Answer (score 2):

This pretty much looks like the data is flawed. To handle this, I would suggest reading each line of the csv file as a single string and the applying a map() function to handle the data

```
case class myClass(name: String, age: Integer, sex: String, siblings: Integer)

val myNewDf = myDf.map(row => {
  val myRow: String = row.getAs[String]("MY_SINGLE_COLUMN")
  val myRowValues = myRow.split(",")
  if (4 == myRowValues.size()) {
      //everything as expected 
      return myClass(myRowValues[0], myRowValues[1], myRowValues[2], myRowValues[3]) 
  } else {
      //do foo to guess missing values
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As in your case Data is not properly formatted. To handle this first data has to be cleansed, i.e all rows of CSV should have same Schema or same no of delimiter/columns.

Basic approach to do this in spark could be:

1. Load data as Text
2. Apply map operation on loaded DF/DS to clean it
3. Create Schema manually
4. Apply Schema on the cleansed DF/DS

Sample Code

```
//Sample CSV
John,28,M,3
Jenny,M,3
//Sample Code
val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = true),
    StructField("sex", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("sib", IntegerType, nullable = true)
  )
)

import spark.implicits._
val rawdf = spark.read.text("test.csv")
rawdf.show(10)
val rdd = rawdf.map(row => {
  val raw = row.getAs[String]("value")
  //TODO: Data cleansing has to be done.
  val values = raw.split(",")
  if (values.length != 4) {
    s"${values(0)},,${values(1)},${values(2)}"
  } else {
    raw
  }
})
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv(rdd)
df.show(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a case class with Optional field for `age` and load your csv with schema directly into a Dataset.

Something like that :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders}
import sparkSession.implicits._

  case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Int], sex: String, siblings: Int)

  val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema

  val dfInput = sparkSession.read
    .format("csv")
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header", "true")
    .load("path/to/csv.csv")
    .as[Person]
```